# Linker errors (LNK2001) when library compiles fine

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, glew

I am trying to compile a small 2D engine I am working on. So far this has gone well, but ever since I included GLEW (as I wanted to start working on some fragment shaders) the test program refuses to build. To clarify, I build the engine as a static library (Mage2D.lib), and then build a test program that uses the library.

This is the error I am getting:

```
1>Link:
1>  libpng15.lib(pngget.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Mage2D_D.lib(root.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewIsSupported@4
1>Mage2D_D.lib(root.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0
1>C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Rose\Debug\MageTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Now normally I realize this means I'm not including the right library into my test program (glew32.lib). But that's impossibly the case here, as I build glew.c into Mage2D.lib. GLEW is literally part of the source code of Mage2D as it seemed convenient to do that with a program that is four files and integral part of the engine anyway.

I followed GLEW's instructions on their website to the letter on how to build GLEW and include it into my project, but I keep getting this error.

What the hell is going on?

Comment: Are the GLEW functions that gave you the error the only GLEW functions you are using?

Comment: At the moment, yes. For now I wanted to simply add GLEW to my project and add a bit of code to Initialise() function of the root class of my engine. It checks if the right version of OpenGL is available for Shader support. (And to see if GLEW would work, of course! Which is the problem :p)

Comment: First two warnings are because you compile code with different settings, /MD vs /MT is particularly critical.  The errors are due to convincing the compiler that you are going to use the DLL version of glew but actually linking the static library version.  Typically controlled with a #define or /D

Comment: I am aware of the first two warnings, I never bothered solving them as the testing application works fine as it doesn't use the libraries in question.
As for the GLEW errors, I have done the defines as instructed by GLEW but without success. I resorted to using a DLL, which I really didn't want to. I'll solve it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked glew.h and I'm quite sure you need to add **GLEW_STATIC** define just before including glew.h:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"
```

Comment: This define should really be set by the build system, not hardcoded in the source. Use `/DGLEW_STATIC` or add it to the list of defines in the project file.

Comment: I solved it now, for some reason this didn't work first. Working on a different project that uses GLEW, I instead included the Source code and defined GLEW_STATIC in glew.c just before the include. Going to accept this.